# iOS: how to assign the app background to UIView at runtime

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, background, uicolor

"A" is the color of the View controller and "B" the color of the UIView containing the UIView I need to modify, called "C".
So I can't use [UIColor clearColor] because it has an other parent in the middle with different color. This view must have the background color of the UIViewController at runtime.
Something like this,

```
    [cview setBackgroundColor:(self.window.backgroundColor)];
```

(it doesn't exist a self.window field, where self is the viewcontroller)

Comment: sorry -- don't quite get. you want A to be the Background behind C?

Comment: yes, if A is red and B is blue, C must be red

Comment: but A may be any possible color so I need to modify C at runtime

Comment: see if one of my answers is for you. both acomplish it

Answer (score 1):

capture A as an IMAGE and set this image as C's backgroundcolor

ios7+

```
id aImg = [a snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES];
[c setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:aImg]];
```

---

iOS6:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(viewA.bounds.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
[viewA renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *aImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
[c setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:aImg]];
```

Comment: app crashes at runtime, but I'm not sure if the fault is mine or these lines'.

Comment: the code is ios7+ :: if aImg != nil? what os version are you using?